# VMWare Horizon Client v2203 fails to launch on Elementary OS 6.1 after fresh installation

Tags: software-installation, thirdpartyapps, release-jolnir

I have a problem with VMware Horizon client v2203 on ElementaryOS 6.1

The client installs fine with absolutely no errors but when I click on the launch icon it just exits the app before even raising a window for it.

**Reinstallation, reboot** didn't help and there is literally no info about any similar issues by anyone else.

Any advice is appreciated, other than what I have **already tried** and mentioned above.

Thanks,

Aladar

Answer (score 1):

After installing it indeed, the window does not open. Trying to run it form the Terminal gives us some nice clues:
[image]

And the issue seems to be pretty common with many distros.
In short, uncomment the `#session required pam_loginuid.so` line in `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` (or `/etc/pam/lightdm-autologin` if you use autologin). After a restart, the application launches normally (seems to not like dark mode too well though...)

[image]

More info on this [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/VMwareHorizon/comments/u11y1w/segmentation_fault_on_linux_303/), credit to the wonderful person who figured it all out.